# Wall clock analysis from Visual Studio Diagnostics Hub

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

The Performance and Diagnostics Hub in Visual Studio is an amazing feature. I use it for diagnosing Memory and high cpu issues while writing code. However, so far I am not able to figure out how to use this tool for troubleshooting low-cpu hang scenarios (or wall-clock analysis). Let's say my application takes long time on waiting a response back from a network or file I/O. Is there anyway of determining this from the Diagnostics windows in Visual Studio during a debugging sessions? I was hoping this analysis could be part of CPU Analysis section in there.

Comment: use WPA for it: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-43-WPT-Wait-Analysis

Comment: Good to know. So its not possible from within Visual Studio?

Comment: it uses both ETW (Event tracing for Windows) so it can be also possible in the hub if MSFT implements it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this blog here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2014/02/28/new-cpu-usage-tool-in-the-performance-and-diagnostics-hub-in-visual-studio-2013/

The CPU Usage tool measures the CPU’s resources in terms of how much time each core in the CPU spends executing your code, it seems that it didn't provide the feature to resolve/collect the low-cpu hang issue.

Maybe you could think about using other tool like the PerfView or the suggestion of magicandre1981.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vancem/2012/11/26/wall-clock-time-analysis-using-perfview/

Comment: Thanks Jack. Yes I can certainly use other tools. I basically wanted to know if that scenario is now possible with VS Diagnostics Hub. Hopefully this capability will be added in VS at some point.